# Please present a sharp upper bound or a tight upper bound for $a^{1/q}-b^{1/q}$ ($a\geq b\geq 0$ and $q>1$).

Tags: inequality

Please present a sharp upper bound or a tight upper bound for $a^{1/q}-b^{1/q},\;$ ($a\geq b\geq 0$ and $q>1$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you give the context:  What have you done towards solving the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need to include in your question where the problem is from, any further context and your thoughts so far if you want to keep getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$$a^{1/q} - b^{1/q} = b^{1/q}\left(\left(1+\frac{a}b-1\right)^{1/q}-1 \right) \leqslant \frac{b^{1/q}}q\left(\frac{a}b-1 \right)$$
with equality when $a=b$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.@Macavity